# LibGdx input data REQUIRED

Tags: libgdx

I am using the code below to ask users for their username.

```
MyTextInputListener listenerz = new MyTextInputListener();
Gdx.input.getTextInput(listenerz, "Create Username", "");
```

I have knowledge in PHP but beginner in Java LibGdx.
I know that in HTML there is a **REQUIRED**

```
<input name='username' required />
```

That's why I wanted to know the equivalent coding in LibGdx for the **REQUIRED** input.

Comment: Can't you just check yourself if the input String is not empty?

Comment: In HTML, the user won't be able to submit the form if the required input is empty, no need for validation. I just wonder if LibGdx has this kind of functionality.

Comment: `the user won't be able to submit the form if the required input is empty` this is true, but the user can easily remove the `required` field in html with his browser, so you should always do backend verification regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if the user entered a valid input you could do something like this:

```
if(input == null || input.length() < minLength) {
    //Invalid input. Do something.
    //You might just ask the user for input again until it is valid.
    MyTextInputListener listenerz = new MyTextInputListener();
    Gdx.input.getTextInput(listenerz, "Create Username", "");
}
```

You should also add that code in the canceled() method of the listener:

```
@Override
public void canceled () {
    MyTextInputListener listenerz = new MyTextInputListener();
    Gdx.input.getTextInput(listenerz, "Create Username", "");
}
```

This way the input window will just repeat itself if invalid input is given.

Comment: your idea is great, if the input is empty then i should pop-up again the Text Input. But i should do nothing when it was CANCELED. Thanks